# Power Supply With UBEC

Tags: power-supply

I am currently working on a Wifi controlled remote car powered by Li-po batteries.
Can I use a 5V 3A UBEC as power supply for the Raspberry Pi to provide steady 5V and power all devices( 2 IR sensors and a high gain usb wifi a dapter with antenna) ?

Or would the 3A fry the board?

Answer (score 1):

The 3A is just the limit. As long as the 5v is within tolerance you will be fine

Answer (score 1):

First of all what you need to know is 3A is the maximum current limit(or maximum that your battery can pump or supply) for your battery and your current requirement(i.e load) depends on how much current your components are using and here your Pi is safe unless and until you exceed 5.25V.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can use it. Your Pi will pull that much current to power itself. That is the max current output limit of yor UBEC.